# Docker file for running spring boot application on docker container?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, docker-container

Hi i am trying to create a docker image with java and maven installed in it with the port 8090 open.

Once the container is upon running i will copy my spring boot project to the container and i will run it from the container.

for that i tried to create docker file. i was able to build the docker image successfully in my local.

when i try to create the container out of it. it is not bringing the container up . i already wasted my 2 days in it .

i used the following docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ENV VERSION 8
ENV UPDATE 152
ENV BUILD 16
ENV SIG aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-${VERSION}-oracle

# install jre
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get upgrade -qqy --no-install-recommends && \
  apt-get install curl unzip bzip2 -qqy && \
  mkdir -p "${JAVA_HOME}" && \
        curl --silent --location --insecure --junk-session-cookies --retry 3 \
          --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
          http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/"${VERSION}"u"${UPDATE}"-b"${BUILD}"/"${SIG}"/jre-"${VERSION}"u"${UPDATE}"-linux-x64.tar.gz \
        | tar -xzC "${JAVA_HOME}" --strip-components=1 && \
  apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove -y curl unzip bzip2 && \
  apt-get autoclean && apt-get --purge -y autoremove && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" 1 && \
        update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javaws" 1 && \
        update-alternatives --set java "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" && \
        update-alternatives --set javaws "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javaws"

EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Note : i want the container to be upon running when i create the container form that image.

Is there any predefined Docker Image in docker hub which can make my work simple ?

I will be happy if you guys give me a docker file to answer my issue.

I know only stackoverflow can fix my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a very simple Spring Guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the endpoint. Have to start the service in endpoint. Once this service (process) gets completed the container Quits.

In my case i have invoked a simple spring boot app in the entry point which listens to the port 8090.

Excellent learning after struggling for more than 2 days .

Answer (score 0):

use multi stage docker build https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

1) let the first stage have the maven image https://hub.docker.com/r/library/maven/ and build the project by copying the project files into it and get the executable jar file

2) copy the jar file into second stage which is by using openjdk image using  https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/ and run the executable jar file in a script at CMD[]

if you use alpine versions of image the docker container size will be very less and efficient